# How can I use my certificate on my CAC to sign an assembly written in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, sign, cac

I want to sign a .NET assembly using the certificate located on my Common Access Card (CAC).  Most instructions I've found involve creating a Personal Information Exchange (.pfx) file from the certificate (.cer) file.  But, during the process of creating a pfx file I'm asked for the private key, which I don't have.  I only have a PIN that allows me to use my CAC to log in and authenticate to network resources which doesn't allow me to use the pfx cert to sign.

I've created strong name key files and used strong name key file to sign assemblies.  For what I'm coding now I must use the certs on my CAC.

I'm looking for the process that allows me to use the certificates on my CAC to sign the assemblies I'm building.